# Unable to Register Gitlab Runner (Certificate Failed)

Tags: ssl, gitlab, letsencrypt

I have a gitlab instance running on my home network.  The hostname `git.example.com` is an IPv6 only dns record, and the nginx server is only listening on `[::]`.

When I try to register the runner with this command:

```
gitlab-runner register -r nyRxyFSx(rest_of_token) -u https://git.example.com/ --tag-list=shared --name shared-runner --run-untagged --tls-cert-file /certs/\*.example.com.cer --tls-key-file /certs/\*.example.com.key
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=nyRxyFSx status=couldn't execute POST against https://git.example.com/api/v4/runners: Post https://git.example.com/api/v4/runners: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
>
> PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems

The certificates I'm using is a LE certificate, but instead of it being registered from the gitlab instance (since ACME was failing with ipv6 only), I just used the certificate for `*.example.com` I have from the OPNSense LE plugin.

How can I ignore this cert error and register the runner?